# How to solve trigonometric complex equations?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 44, exercise 6, he asks the solution set of the equations: $\cos z=0$ and $\sin z=0$, where $z\in \mathbb C$.

I've already tried to use the definition of $\cos z$ and $\sin z$ as power series and the equality $\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ and $\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ without any success.

Any help is welcome

Comment: Are those hyperbolic functions? Then perhaps you missed the "h" in $\cosh$ and $\sinh$.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat no, they aren't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
The equations are equivalent to 
$$\mathrm e^{2\mathrm i z}=-1,\quad\text{resp.}\enspace \mathrm e^{2\mathrm i z}=1,$$
and the complex exponential function is periodic, with period $2\mathrm i\pi$.